# On Linux, how do I recursively copy files while ignoring certain names?

Tags: linux, unix, shell, scripting, copy

I need to recursively copy a directory tree, ignoring any subdirectories named 'CVS'. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: This belong either on Serverfault or Superuser.

Comment: It's tagged 'scripting' so it's good here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
tar -cpf - --exclude=CVS directory | sh -c 'cd /wherever/it/goes && tar -xpf -'
```

Modify the right-hand `tar`'s options to `-xvpf` if you'd like to see what's going on.

Comment: I would change the ";" in there to "&&" so that if there is a typo in the pathname, the files won't end up in the wrong place.

Answer (score 15):

```
rsync -av --exclude=CVS <src> <dst>
```

Comment: this is definitely the right answer. he was looking for a direct linux copy excluding a pattern. rsync is the way to go > cp

Answer (score 7):

Why not approach it from a slightly different angle and check out the files from CVS using the export command.

This'll give you the directories without any of the CVS artifacts.